# How to update matplotlib subplots on a tkinter Canvas?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I want to update subplots that are embedded into a `Canvas` in a tkinter GUI. Whatsoever I try, my intention fails. See how far I am:

```
from tkinter import *
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

root = Tk()

figId = plt.figure()

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figId, master=root)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
canvas.draw()

vals1 = [5, 6, 3, 9]
vals2 = vals1

for i in range(0, len(vals1)+1):
    toPlot = vals1[0:i]
    plt.subplot(211).plot(toPlot)
    plt.subplot(212).plot(toPlot)
    time.sleep(1)

root.mainloop()
```

I figured out that doing something like `plt.pause(.1)` is not the right way. For me, it seems that I have to introduce `matplotlib.animation`, but I really have no clue how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
import random
from itertools import count
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from tkinter import *
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)

x_vals = []
y_vals1 = []
y_vals2 = []

index = count()

root = Tk()
figId = plt.figure()
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figId, master=root)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
canvas.draw()

def animate(i):
    x_vals.append(next(index))
    y_vals1.append(random.randint(0, 5))
    y_vals2.append(random.randint(0, 5))
    plt.cla()
    plt.plot(x_vals, y_vals1)
    plt.plot(x_vals, y_vals2)

ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, interval=1000)

root.mainloop()
```